# Starting running all build configuration in TeamCity

Tags: build, teamcity

In TC there is a project with a couple build configurations. Build configs targets projects that not interfere with each other - so I can start the build process simultaneously. On each build configuration home page there is Run button that starts the build.

My question - there is possible to create a such button that triggers the build of all configs?

I know that there is Build triggers and so on - but sometime there is need to start all build configuration - "on demand" build run - and it is a little inconvenient to go to each home page and press Run button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a 'kick-off' build configuration -- it doesn't need to do anything -- and linking each of your parallel configurations to it by a `Finish Build` trigger.  When you `Run...` the 'kick-off' configuration, it'll finish quickly and all of the parallel configurations should then get triggered.

Comment: Can you add some more details? do I need to define two identical builds twice or Can I pass just build confirations params somehow?

Comment: The way I understand it, you define a new build configuration (I called it "Kickoff") that does nothing and put it before everything.  Then all the other build configurations that you want done in parallel, make them trigger on the completion of the "Kickoff" build.  This way, the first thing that will get run is Kickoff, which will finish immediately because it does nothing.  All the other builds that are waiting for Kickoff to finish, should start at the same time making parallel build configurations run.